# Why redirection rule I've added to my .htaccess disappears?

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm a total newbie so please forgive if it's a stupid question but something weird is happening. I've added custom redirection rule to my .htaccess file `RewriteRule ^/?hosts/(.*)$ /user/$1 [R,L]`.
After some time, that rule is just gone from the .htaccess file. All other rules are in place. Only that rule gets removed. Any idea why?

```
 # BEGIN WordPress
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^/?hosts/(.*)$ /user/$1 [R,L]
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
    </IfModule>

    # END WordPress
```

Comment: Wordpress has a lot of security plugins that can edit the htaccess file. Have you checked to see if they overwrote your htaccess?

Comment: But why those plugins remove it I don't understand..

Comment: Is there any way to keep the rule if other plugins try to edit it?

Comment: Probably not, unless you want to identify the culprit plugin and disable it, or do something crazy like run a cron job regularly to restore your .htaccess file. Personally, I'd choose the former option

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress will rewrite everything between the `# BEGIN WordPress` and `# END WordPress` tags every time that permalinks are rebuilt.

Place your rule above the `# BEGIN Wordpress` comment:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?hosts/(.*)$ /user/$1 [R,L]

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?hosts/(.*)$ /user/$1 [R,L]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```